# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression for ng-click using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is driving me nuts.  It works fine, but in the console it's giving me that error.  The line of code is from a according menu using Angular and UI-Router

```
<li ng-repeat="item in group.items"><a ng-click="setActiveView(item['item-title'])" ui-sref="dashboard.showname.{{item['item-title']}}">{{item['item-title']}}</a></li>
```

The actual error message says:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[ng-click='setActiveView(item['item-title'])']
```

Is this a bug?  or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you tell me please what you have to do. i mean when i am click on any title page will be changed or something else

Comment: I'm having kind of same error in console, in what "level" in the state tree are you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the nested quotes are creating the issue. Can you use:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in group.items">
    <a ng-click="setActiveView(item.item-title)" 
        ui-sref="dashboard.showname.{{item.item-title}}">
        {{item.item-title}}
    </a>
</li>
```

instead?

Comment: If you use "-" in a property name, you can't access like "item.property-with-this" you must use the "array form" for it :)